# Compare java.util.Calendar date to java.util.Date

Tags: java, java.util.date, date-comparison, java.util.calendar

I need to compare a Calendar time to Date. I wrote below code.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Date date = new Date();
date.setSeconds(0);
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(now.getTime());
System.out.println(date.compareTo(now.getTime()));
```

Output is

```
Fri Dec 01 16:54:00 IST 2017
Fri Dec 01 16:54:00 IST 2017
1
```

It seems util date is bigger than calendar date. Why is it failing? what is the write way of comparing these dates?

**Edit 1:-**
My problem is I need to compare a util date (stored in database) lets say 2017-12-01 16:41:00.0 to current Date and time, what is write approach?

Comment: Could the milliseconds/nanoseconds be off?

Comment: Milliseconds rather than nanoseconds, but yes, that'll be what's wrong, I'm sure. Show `Date.getTime()` to make it clear exactly which values are being represented. That still won't *always* show 0 though, as the clock could "tick" between constructing the Calendar and constructing the Date.

Comment: Note: even if you correct this, the Date could have a newer time even after truncating the seconds as it occurs slightly later in this example.

Comment: Be aware that [`Date.setSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setSeconds-int-) is deprecated. Technicly, the `Date` class is/will be deprecated.

Comment: Slightly aside, you shouldn’t want to compare the two at all. Both classes, `Date` and `Calendar` are long outdated and replaced by [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And that doesn’t have the same distinction between date and calendar, so you will never have the issue. I warmly recommend you use `java.time` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Check the millis:

```
    System.out.println(now.getTime().getTime());
    System.out.println(date.getTime());
    System.out.println(now.getTime().getTime() - date.getTime());
```

Then you see that there (sometimes) is a difference.

Comment: Yes I am getting a negative value. It means util date is bigger than calendar date.

Comment: Yes, you create `date` after you create `now`. So `date` will be bigger (or same as `now`). (If you like this answer, feel free to mark it as 'accepted'.)

Comment: I understand what you said. But my problem is if I need to compare a util date (stored in database) to current Date and time, what is write approach?

Comment: You could compare now.getTime().getTime() / 1000 == date.getTime() / 1000 (even though it is not very pretty).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to remove the seconds/millis is to count the number of minutes

```
// compare the minutes, ignoring the seconds/milli-seconds.
if (now.getTime().getTime() / 60_000 == date.getTime() / 60_000)
```

You can also use TimeUnit

```
if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime().getTime()) == 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(date.getTime()))
```

if you prefer to use a library than maths.